# How to upload a file from client to server and then server to server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, axios, multipartform-data

In my web application I need to upload the files.I have used axios to send file as requests from client to server(api) with form data append and also necessary headers.Now the ask is that I have to pass the file from server(api) to another endpoint api.Since I am using next js,both client and server api handling is done from my side

The client request is fine with binary data and all.But I don't know how to pass it from the server(api) to another server(api) using axios with the request got from client.As this is a very unusual requirement, there are no available solutions in online.

I would be glad if I can have some solution or an implementation

Comment: This is not an unusual requirement. You should make a web request to the endpoint from your server. [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) can be used in the backend too. You should read the documentation of your backend language to learn how an HTTP(S) request is made.

Comment: I have implemented the solution for client to server,my ask is that when the server gets the request from client.Now how do I pass the same request to the another server,with the same data.I wanted to know about that,on how it can be implemented.Since it's a form data,how should I do it,should I parse it and then again convert binary or we can do directly via the same request.That is what I want to know

Answer (score 0):

```
import axios from 'axios';

async function sendFileToEndpoint(file) {
  try {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);

    const response = await axios.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://endpoint-api.com/upload',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
      data: formData,
    });
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

In this example, the *sendFileToEndpoint* function accepts a file as an argument and sends it to the endpoint API using a POST request with **multipart/form-data** content type. You can adjust the request options as needed to meet the requirements of the endpoint API.

It's up to you to manage the server.